# Ошибка arr.sort is not a function

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Пытаюсь отсортировать по возрастанию массив из четных чисел. Попробовал два решения, но срабатывает только второй вариант

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему первый вариант кода выдает ошибку "arr.sort is not a function"

Первый вариант:

```js
let newArray = [234,23,235,78,78,7,3568,46,78,456];

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

for (let i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
  if (newArray[i] % 2 === 0) {
    // console.log(newArray[i]);
    let arr = newArray[i];
    console.log(arr.sort(compareNumbers)); 
  }
}
```

Второй вариант:

```js
let newArray1 = [234,23,235,78,78,7,3568,46,78,456];

function order(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
console.log(newArray1.sort(order))

let arr1 = newArray1.sort(order);

for (let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr1[i] % 2 ===0) {
    console.log(arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что это значит?

> отсортировать по возрастанию массив из четных чисел

---

```
let arr = newArray[i];
```

`arr` - элемент массива, число. У числа нет метода `sort`.